# copy of files in windows cmd batch

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, batch-processing

I really cannot find anything to this problem:

I have a folder C:\dir1\dir2 I get this directory via reading a file so I don't know the name of dir1 or dir2 upfront. I want to copy dir2 into a target directory C:\target. At the end I want to have C:\target\dir2 and that dir2 in target shall have all the files which have been in the source of dir2. When I try xcopy with /s switch it copies the files in the source dir2 directly into target without creating dir2 in target. How can I make sure that this directory is created?

I must achieve that dir2 is created automatically.

EDIT:

```
for /F "tokens=*" %%i in (%maindir%\mydir.txt) do call :process2 %%i
:process2
set sourcefile=%*
xcopy /s "%sourcefile%" target
```

is basically the part of my batch file in question. Where in mydir.txt I get some directory like C:\dir1\dir2 which contains files file1 file2 etc. In target I have now

target\file1
target\file2

but I want target\dir2\file1 and target\dir2\file2

Hope that makes it a bit clearer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=c:\sourcedir\with space"
SET "destdir=c:\destdir"
FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN ("%sourcedir%") DO (
 XCOPY /s "%sourcedir%" "%destdir%\%%~nxa\"
)
GOTO :EOF
```

This should get the job done for you. I'll presume you've already got `sourcedir` set from your file – I just used a directory I had which happens to contain spaces in its name. Possibly you'd want to append `>nul` to the `XCOPY` line to suppress messages.

Comment: getting maybe a bit closer, my problem here is that %%~nxa is not being replaced. I get now a subdirectory called "%~nxa" instead of the name of the source directory.

Comment: found a work around to set some variables in the for loop before calling the sub process. I have no idea why %%a only seems to work partially in the sub process. Key was here %%~nxa. Thanks.

Comment: @AndyAndroid: Now that you have shown the relevant part of your script, it seems clear why you had issues with `%%~nxa`. You are calling `XCOPY` in a subroutine that is called in a loop while this answer is calling `XCOPY` directly in the loop, and `%%~nxa` cannot have the intended meaning outside the context of that loop. Perhaps you could avoid using additional variables if you: 1) included quotation marks around `%%i` in the `call` command: `call :process2 "%%i"`; 2) invoked `xcopy` (in your `process2` subroutine) something like this: `XCOPY /s %1 "%target%\%~nx1\"`.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a little unclear, but if I understand it correctly, you should have a look at the [mkdir](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/mkdir.mspx?mfr=true) command. That will make your directory - only if the directory doesn't already exist. The syntax is:

```
MKDIR [drive:]path
```

For example, `mkdir \2014\photos\beach` makes the directory "2014" in the current directory ( use `CD`) with the sub folders "photos" and "beach".

That being said, if you have proper syntax for `xcopy`, it should create the new directory for you *IF it doesn't already exist*. Have a look again at [xcopy](http://ss64.com/nt/xcopy.html).

If the directory does exist, this is a pretty "sure-fire" way to remove it before trying to make it again:

```
if exist {directory} rd /s /q {directory}
```

Comment: I don't know the name of the directory. Parsing a long string to find the name of the directory seems to be too much for copying a directory with contents. I want basically what I do in Windows explorer when I copy and paste a directory with content.